# Why won't my scrollbars synchronise properly?

Tags: qt, user-interface, scrollbar

I've evaluated several ways to create a QTableView with a hierarchic header and decided on faking it (seemed easy at the time). So I created my first QTableView with everything it needs and added a second on top, which only shows the header. I set it up so it looks nice and all, and then started to synch the scrollbars. 
The vertical scrollbar was not a problem, since the 'fake header' table won't scroll vertically.
The horizontal scrollbar seemed to be okay too, until I noticed that the tables scroll at different speeds. So basically my 'fake Header' scrolls faster than my actual table. The illusion of one header is quite literally ripped apart.
Now I was thinking, maybe they scroll at a relative pace to their size, so I adjusted the width of both tables to be exactly the same. This didn't change anything, though.
So, I'm out of ideas for now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the sliders move at different pace as well or just the view?

Comment: To make it seems like one single table, I hid the fake header's scrollbar, so I don't know that yet. I'll check that.

Comment: Indeed, the sliders also move at a different pace.

Comment: I'm suspecting that your scrollbars don't have the same range. You should connect the [rangeChanged(int,int)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractslider.html#rangeChanged) signal from one of your scrollbars to some function, where you set the range of your other scrollbar to those values.

Comment: Consider adding a custom header widget using `QTableView::setHorizontalHeader`. It seems to be the proper way to do what you want.

Comment: @thuga: That did the trick, thank you very much. I suggest you post a full-fledged answer, so I can accept it and this question is displayed as 'answered'.

Comment: @Riateche: That's definitely the long-term goal, not sure how soon I'll find the time, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that your scrollbars don't have the same range. You should connect the rangeChanged(int,int) signal from one of your scrollbars to some function, where you set the range of your other scrollbar to those values.